# Form EMPTY select option to PHP

Tags: php, forms

Look around and could find an answer for my problem

I have a form that's processed by PHP, but I cannot pass the select option (it passes blank), no matter what option I choose.

My select code

```
<form id="contact-form">
  <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
      <option value="" selected="">Escolher:</option>
      <option value="service">General Customer Service</option>
      <option value="suggestions">Suggestions</option>
      <option value="product">Product Support</option>
   </select>
 </form>
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["subject"]) || empty($_POST["message"]) || !filter_var($_POST["email"],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "Error";
    return false;
   }
```

It always trigger error because $_POST["subject"] is empty

Help! :)

Comment: Where are name and email fields in your form?

Comment: Are you sure it is empty? Try `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: I just posted the part of the code that doesn't work

Comment: I have a feeling you might have form tags inside of form tags, could you paste your whole html please?

Comment: It will keep on tiggering and triggering even if subject is filled, up until you add `method="post"`. Forms default to GET without it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yup, that got it fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a method on your form element to tell it to use POST rather than GET.

Change this:

```
<form id="contact-form">
```

to this:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put method="POST" into this tag:

```
<form id="contact-form">

<form id="contact-form" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the form you showed, this will be enough:

```
if(empty($_POST["subject"]) && !isset($_POST["subject"]))
   {
    echo "Error";
    return false;
 }
```

But you are mentioning lot of other variables that are not posted from this form, and that is your problem.

Also add `method="POST"` to your form.

Comment: Dont you mean subject??

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="contact-form" action="" method="post">
```

try this.